# Three.js increase box geometry from only one side

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry

I'm new in three.js, and my first feature was to create a box geometry which can increased from only one side.

**Problem : When you increase width or height of an object the two sides automatically increased.**

[jsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/hfj7gm6t/5207/)

So i lost 1 hour, to find the good algorythm :

```
    geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(strength, 200, 200);
    material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 0xff0000
    });

    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    mesh.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation( - strength + strength / 2, 0, 0 ) );
```

Someone can explain me: **- strength + strength / 2** (If i increase the strength by 1 the translation is only -0.5 not -1 ?)

What is the name of this sort of algorythm, where i can find good ressources to learn this purpose (beginner)?

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Some good three resources here:

https://threejs.org/examples/

and:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Getting-Started

Comment: Try with and without this line in the jsFiddle : `mesh.applyMatrix( new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation( - strength + strength / 2, 0, 0 ) );` change init() argument value to understand.

Comment: Yeah i see that you are doing a weird transformation to the mesh... but why? and what are you trying to achieve on a high level?

Comment: No this is my complete feature i succeeded what i wanted ! 
I can't understand this:  
**- strength + strength / 2** 
Why it works ? and i search good ressources to learn 3D geometry algorythm... to not search formula randomly

Comment: That's not really an *algorithm*. It's just some kind of transformation. But I still don't understand WHAT you are trying to achieve. If i understood what you were trying to achieve, i might be able to advise you on better ways.

The result of -strength + strength / 2 depends on operator precedence. If you put some parenthesis around the various parts of the expression, it might make it more clear. like (-strength) + (strength/2)

Comment: Are you trying to scale a cube away from it's edge, instead of from it's center point?

Comment: For instance. you could just offset the cube to it's upper left corner, like you are doing now... like .makeTranslation( 100,100,100 ), and then just use mesh.scale.set( 10,20,30) or whatever to control the scaling... 

Generally you don't want to do mesh.applyMatrix more than once.. .since it is a slow operation because it modifies the actual vertices, and will result in drift if you keep applying transformations to the vertices over and over. Instead you want to use the mesh.scale and mesh.position to control things, since those are single values that are designed to be updated dynamically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also, you can shift the geometry with `.translate()` method, thus you won't have a container object in the scene graph:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(60, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.set(2, 3, 5);
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

scene.add(new THREE.GridHelper(10, 10));

var boxGeom = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
boxGeom.translate(0.5, 0.5, 0); // pivot point is shifted
var box = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeom, new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial());
scene.add(box);

var clock = new THREE.Clock();
var delta = 0;
var time = 0;

render();

function render() {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  delta = clock.getDelta();
  time += delta;

  box.scale.set(2.5 + Math.sin(time) * 2, 1.5, 1.5);

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/95/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Comment: Powerful ! Please can you explain that `2.5 + Math.sin(time) * 2`, how do you find this sort of formula ?
Thanks!

Comment: @user3703539 You're welcome :) Well... The sinus function gives you values in range from -1 to 1, thus when you multiply it by 2, you'll get range from -2 to 2 ) I used 2 just in case of example, to show how the things work :)

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
var container = new THREE.Object3D()
var boxMesh = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1));
boxMesh.position.set(0.5,0.5,0.5)
container.add(boxMesh)

scene.add(container)

container.scale.set(strength,200,200);
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scene_graph